# Fancybox 2, change title description to alt

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a link like this

```
<a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="gallery1" href="images/large/9.png"  title="project description here >> <a href='http://www.google.com'target='_blank'>View website</a>"> <img src="images/thumbs/107.png" alt="" /></a>
```

but on hovering it shows the code. After toying around with many things, I've decided that switching the title description to the `alt` field would solve my problem, but cannot figure out how to do this. 
I am assuming its in the jquery.fancybox.js file, and I just need to switch it. Can anyone help?

UPDATE: I found a better solution without moving the title description to the alt field I can disable the hover feature with this code

```
var tempTitle = "";
$('a[title]').hover(
function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     tempTitle = $(this).attr('title');

     $(this).attr('title', '');

         $(this).mousedown(
            function(){
                $(this).attr('title', tempTitle);
            }
        );
 }
 ,
 function() {
   $(this).attr('title', tempTitle);
 }
 );
```

Works like a charm!

Comment: I mistakenly voted to close this question, thinking it was duplicated with another one, my bad. Please ignore my close vote.

Answer (score 0):

If having this html :

```
<a class="fancybox-effects-c" rel="gallery1" href="images/large/9.png"><img src="images/thumbs/107.png" alt="project description here &gt;&gt; <a href='http://www.google.com'target='_blank'>View website</a>" /></a>
```

.... where the wanted caption for fancybox is in the `alt` attribute of the `img` tag (thumbnail), then use this code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-effects-c").fancybox({
        beforeShow: function() {
            this.title = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt');
        }
    }); // fancybox
}); // ready​
```

**NOTICE** that I used `&gt;` instead of `>` to avoid script issues.

See **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/22ywQ/)**

Comment: JFK! thank you so much, but for some reason its not using the fancybox-effects-c anymore. its bizarre... as you can see in the demo, thats not effect-c, and it also spans wider than the page. any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<a class="fancybox-effects-c" 
   rel="gallery1" href="images/large/9.png" 
   title="project description here >> <a href='http://www.google.com' target='_blank'>View website</a>">
<img src="images/thumbs/107.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

There was no space before the `target` in your `title`

Comment: Corrected a typo but didn't actually answer the question.

Comment: thanks! fixed the typo and the alt tag is now working for fancybox description, however its not using fancybox-effects-c anymore?!